# Add CSS to show Selected Item in asp:Repeater

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Is it possible to add CSS to the selected item in an asp:Repeater?  I'm trying to bold the selected item.  I tried using OnClientClick but couldn't get it to work.

Here is my asp:Repeater LinkButton code:

```
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptFeatures" runat="server" OnItemCommand="listItem_ItemCommand">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="getFeatures"  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccessListItemId") %>'></asp:LinkButton><br />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

> Update: Using the suggestion of Laslos (thank you), I updated my template like this:

```
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptFeatures" runat="server" OnItemCommand="listItem_ItemCommand">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccessListItemId") %>"  onclick="javascript:addClass('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccessListItemId") %>')">
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="getFeatures"  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccessListItemId") %>'></asp:LinkButton><br />
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

and added function:

```
        function addClass(control) {
        $('#' + control).addClass('selected');
    }
```

It updates the class briefly, but loses it as soon as the postback is completed.  Anyone with any additional suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes it's possible are you familiar with how to point to the css class that you are wanting to use..? fist thing I would have done is a simple google search tons of CSS examples and how to use them in your aspx Markup code

Comment: Yes, I know How to point to the css class that I want.  What I don't know is how to apply to the "selected" item.

Comment: these all have attributes that you can apply for example if you have it wrapped around a <div> like I stated , there are plenty of examples on how to do this on the web..

Comment: There is no <div>, it is in ItempTemplate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795895/apply-stylesheet-to-gridview-templatefields please use google and type `C# CSS on ItemTemplate` good luck

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is regarding a Gridview with table cells.  I am using neither, but thanks.

Comment: have you executed any valid google search or are you expecting some quick fix / answer..? just curious

Comment: `asp:Repeater` does not have built-in functionality for a selected item, I would wrap a `<div>` around the `asp:LinkButton` in the `ItemTemplate`, set a CSS class to the `<div>` and update the class to what you want on client click.

Comment: @MethodMan - really, dude?  Considering you couldn't produce a valid example of my issue either, why would you think that I hadn't done a Google search?  I don't post questions until I have thoroughly searched for an example or anything that could help.

Comment: Good luck dude, and I am not going to do the work for you..

Comment: I never asked you to.

Comment: Maybe add a `asp:HiddenField`, store the selected item's id into it, then in the `$(document).ready` add something like `$('#' + $('#hiddenField').val()).addClass('selected');`

Comment: @Laslos - Thank you so much for your help.  I had to modify your suggested code a bit, but it works perfectly.  I would not have thought about that option.  I have been working with AngularJs and MVC recently and this is the first time in like 15 years that I have had to work with webforms.  I so appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what finally worked (for anyone who may find they need this).  I added a asp:HiddenField to the page:

```
  <asp:HiddenField ID="SelectedItem" runat="server" />
```

In the _ItemCommand in the code-behind I set the value of the hidden field to the ID of the the selected link:

```
        protected void listItem_ItemCommand(Object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItem.Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

added the following to the document.ready function:

```
            var selectedItem= $("[id*=SelectedItem]").val();
        $('#' + selectedItem).addClass('selected');
```

I really hope this helps someone else, because after a lot of searching the internet I couldn't find an answer.  Thanks again @Laslos, could not have done it without you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify this without the need for hidden fields.

Something like:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFeatures" runat="server" OnItemCommand="listItem_ItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="getFeatures"  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccessListItemId") %>'></asp:LinkButton><br />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**C#**

```
protected void listItem_ItemCommand(Object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string exisitingClass = ((LinkButton)source).CssClass + " ";
    ((LinkButton)source).CssClass = exisitingClass.Trim() + "selected";
}
```

Now all you have to do is create your CSS class.

**NOTE** some debugging may be required, this is untested and off the top of my head.