# Case convert (text-transform) on click using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a text area in WordPress where I can type/paste any text and by clicking on the button, all of them should be UPPER/lower CASE (using HTML and CSS).

Here is the code I have added to the top of the content:

```
HTML area;
<div id="form">
<textarea placeholder="Type or paste text here"></textarea>
<div class="wp-block-columns">
<div class="wp-block-column"><button type="button" class="uppercase">UPPER CASE</button></div>
<div class="wp-block-column"><button type="button" class="lowercase">lower case</button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS that I used in theme custom CSS setting:

```
#form textarea {
height: 25vh;
min-height: 7.25em;
max-height: 67vh;
resize: vertical;
}
#form .wp-block-columns {
margin: 0;
}
#form .wp-block-column {
margin-top: 0.5rem;
margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
#form button {
width: 100%;
}
.wp-block-column.uppercase {
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.wp-block-column.lowercase {
text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

The text area is fine, buttons are good but the text is not converting. I am new and tried many things all day so now I need expert advice. Thanks

Comment: There were other ways too like using JS or PHP but again I am a beginner!

Comment: Add a space in between class names -.wp-block-column .lowercase { }
Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558721/css-classes-subclasses

Comment: it doesn't affect the results, the buttons are not working. https://jsbin.com/bocecam/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it using input and label HTML tags. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
HTML area;
<input type="radio" name="case" id="upper-case">
<input type="radio" name="case" id="lower-case">
<div id="form">
  <textarea class="a" placeholder="Type or paste text here"></textarea>
  <div class="wp-block-columns">
   <div class="wp-block-column">
     <label class="uppercase" for="upper-case">
       UPPER CASE
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class="wp-block-column">
     <label class="lowercase" for="lower-case">
       lower case
     </label>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#form textarea {
height: 25vh;
min-height: 7.25em;
max-height: 67vh;
resize: vertical;
}
#form .wp-block-columns {
margin: 0;
}
#form .wp-block-column {
margin-top: 0.5rem;
margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
#form button {
width: 100%;
}
#upper-case:checked ~ #form textarea {
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#lower-case:checked ~ #form textarea {
text-transform: lowercase;
}
input {
  visibility: hidden;
}
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this working. Can you refer to me a blog or site for advanced learning? @Ezzeldien Rashad

Comment: @Ali [javascipt.info](https://javascript.info/) is the best website for learning js. For HTML and CSS you can learn from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) and use [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/) as a reference. You can also take a look at [The books at goalkicker](https://books.goalkicker.com/), they are really helpful.

Comment: I will follow your advice, thanks!